# concat a string with RichTextBox content in C#

Tags: c#

I'm saving a text typed in a `RichTextBox` to file as the following :

```
richTextBox1.SaveFile(sfd.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
```

I want when I'm saving the content of the `RichTextBox` to concat a string with that content.

How can I do that ?

## Edit 1

I tried to concat using + but it wont work

[image]

Comment: Is it WinForms or WPF?

Comment: @StepUp its a winform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate your additions to control's Text property, then call SaveFile method perhaps, like this:

```
richTextBox1.Text += "abc";
richTextBox1.SaveFile(sfd.FileName);
```

Or the better solution would be just get the string from `richTextBox1.Text` property and concatenate with yours and save using `System.IO.File.WriteAllText`.

Answer (score 0):

Use below Code that Works Fine For you..

```
richTextBox1.AppendText("Your string" + Environment.NewLine);
richTextBox1.SaveFile(Saved_File, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
```

Answer (score -1):

Just concatenate your string/ text after all text is added to `Richtextbox`:

```
string yourText="your text to append";
richTextBox1.AppendText("\n" + yourText);
richTextBox1.SaveFile(Saved_File, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
```